# Refresh Outlook mailbox view

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am currently developing an Outlook Add-In with JavaScript. In the background, I use EWS to update emails.

Problem: In Outlook, the modified mail is not refreshed. Is there a possibility to use JavaScript to trigger a refresh?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot update emails using the client side JS APIs and need to do EWS? Would there be client side JS APIs that can help your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by Outlook Web Add-ins today. I would recommend adding your suggestion to the [Office Developer UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).